# Getting data from FAT12 file

Tags: c, fat

So for starters, this is part of some homework. The assignment is getting data from a FAT12 file. 
my problem is that when I run my code, i get bogus values (huge negative numbers) returning from my functions. However if I just run one or 2 of the functions I get the correct value.

My Functions:
My functions follow the same pattern, just with different offsets in fseek and fread.

```
void getOSName(FILE *fp, char *osname)
{
    fseek(fp,3L,SEEK_SET);
    fread(osname,1,8,fp);
}
int totalSize(FILE *fp)
{
    int *tmp1 = malloc(sizeof(int));
    int *tmp2 = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if (tmp1 == 0 || tmp2 == 0)
    {
        printf("Malloc of tmp in function 'totalSize' failed\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    int retVal;
    fseek(fp,0xb,SEEK_SET);
    fread(tmp1,1,2,fp);

    fseek(fp,0x13,SEEK_SET);
    fread(tmp2,1,2,fp);
    if (tmp2 == 0)
    {
        // pverflow, value is larger than 65535 blocks
        //looking in offset
        printf("In tmp2 IF\n");
        fseek(fp,0x20,SEEK_SET);
        fread(tmp2,1,2,fp);
    }
    retVal = *tmp1 * (*tmp2);
    free(tmp1);
    free(tmp2);

    return retVal;
}
int NumberFAT(FILE *fp)
{


    int *tmp1 = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if (tmp1 == 0)
    {
        printf("Malloc of tmp in function 'NumberFAT' failed\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    int retVal;
    fseek(fp,16L,SEEK_SET);
    fread(tmp1,1,1,fp);
    retVal = *tmp1;
    free(tmp1);
    return retVal;
}
```

Main function

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp =  FileIn(argc,argv,"r");

    char *osname = malloc(sizeof(char)*8);
    if (osname == 0 )
    {
        printf("Malloc Failed\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    int size,size2, Filenumb, FATnumb, FATsec;  

    getOSName(fp,osname);
    printf("OS Name: %s\n", osname);


    size = totalSize(fp);
    printf("Total size of disk: %d\n", size);   //always returns correct value

    size2 = freeSpace(fp);
    printf("Free size of the disk: %d :: %d\n",size-size2,size2); //Value is wrong due to incorrect logic

    printf("==============\n");
    Filenumb=numberFiles(fp);
    printf("The number of files in the root directory (not including subdirectories): %d\n",Filenumb);  //should get 3, get 224 by itself, 2144599840 with other functions 

    printf("\n==============\n");

    FATsec=NumberFAT(fp);
    printf("Number of FAT copies: %d\n",FATsec);  //should and do get 2 by itself, -214400062 with other functions

    FATnumb=Sectors(fp);
    printf("Sectors per FAT: %d\n",FATnumb); // should and do get 9 by itself, -21400055 with other functions       
    free(osname);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to say my issue is a pointer issue, I just don't see where or how. 
any insight on how and why my results are wonky would be much appreciated.

Comment: `fread(tmp1,1,1,fp);` - what does *tmp1 contain before and after this statement?

Comment: before it holds a large - number, after it holds what gets returned
shouldn't malloc clear the space allocated?

Comment: ? malloc doesn't clear anything; it allocates memory

Comment: i was thinking of Calloc. should i clear the memory for tmp1 before i use it in fread?

Comment: How many bytes does `fread(tmp1,1,1,fp);` read?

Comment: just reads the one byte

Comment: And how big is `tmp1`?

Comment: tmp1 is the size of a single int.

Comment: Which might be (and in fact almost certainly is) more than one byte... so you are reading one byte from the file into part of `tmp1`, and the rest of `tmp1` contains what it did before.

Comment: ok i can see that. so then then why does it work the first time i run it? wouldn't tmp1 contain whatever garbage is at that location and give that answer?

Comment: The garbage is allowed to be 0 sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to read part of an `int` with `fread`. Just do it the simple way, with `getc`, which reads one byte and returns it (or returns `EOF` if there are no more bytes to read - which  you can handle if you want).

```
int NumberFAT(FILE *fp)
{
    fseek(fp,16L,SEEK_SET);
    return getc(fp);
}
```

Comment: @Belrouk `int first_byte = getc(fp); int second_byte = getc(fp);` and then do something with them? (Maybe `return (first_byte | (second_byte * 256));`)

Comment: that seems awkward, but that will work.  mybe i should post another question on this, but what's the difference between getc and fread?

Comment: @Belrouk Your problem isn't that you're using `fread`, it's that you're not reading the entire variable, so part of it still contains garbage. (You don't *have* to use `getc` to read a 2-byte integer, but you asked how to do it so I told you...)

Comment: @Belrouk also the question is about reading one character, and `getc` is a much easier way to read one character.